# neo4j-admin database load throw java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: neo4j

I was using neo4j Aura DB for a non-profit university project
As now we have funidng for renting VM from our own university, we desired to migrate the data from neo4j Aura to the VM in the same LAN such that the intra-application traffic would be faster.

The neo4j version is 5.7.0. The VM is an  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-47-generic x86_64) machine.

I am trying to load the dump downloaded from Aura and an error occurs.

> root@DPT-X-11011:~# neo4j-admin version /etc/default/neo4j: line 22:
> server.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687: command not found neo4j 5.7.0
>
> root@DPT-X-11011:~# ../bin/neo4j-admin database load neo4j --from-path=./snapshot/31-5-2023/ --overwrite-destination=true
> /etc/default/neo4j: line 22: server.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687: command not found
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libzstd-jni-1.5.4-215256062990507315695.so: /tmp/libzstd-jni-1.5.4-215256062990507315695.so: failed to map segment from shared object
> no zstd-jni-1.5.4-2 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
> Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /linux/amd64/libzstd-jni-1.5.4-2.so or load zstd-jni-1.5.4-2 from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni-1.5.4-2 in your system.
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native$1.run(Native.java:69)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native$1.run(Native.java:67)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:67)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:154)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:85)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdInputStreamNoFinalizer.(ZstdInputStreamNoFinalizer.java:23)
> at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdInputStream.(ZstdInputStream.java:24)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.StandardCompressionFormat$2.decompress(StandardCompressionFormat.java:67)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.DumpZstdFormatV1.decompress(DumpZstdFormatV1.java:37)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.DumpFormatSelector.decompress(DumpFormatSelector.java:44)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.Loader.openArchiveIn(Loader.java:212)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.Loader.load(Loader.java:115)
> at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.Loader.load(Loader.java:77)
> at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadDumpExecutor.load(LoadDumpExecutor.java:97)
> at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadDumpExecutor.execute(LoadDumpExecutor.java:74)
> at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadCommand.loadDump(LoadCommand.java:197)
> at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadCommand.execute(LoadCommand.java:150)
> at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
> at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
> at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
> at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
> at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
> at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
> at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
> at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
> at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
> at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
> at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:94)
> at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:82)

Answer (score 0):

An absurd fix you can do is to take the jar from maven, https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/luben/zstd-jni/, that matches the version in the error (so 1.5.4-2 in your case),

and unzip it, e.g. `unzip zstd-jni-1.5.4-2.jar`. It'll extract to a bunch of folders, such as `linux`, `freebsd`, `darwin`, `com`, and a few others.
Then, take the .so it is looking for, in your case `linux/amd64/libzstd-jni-1.5.4-2.so`, and copy it to `/usr/lib`. It should be happy afterwords.